# Select all with MAX id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `machines` and a table `machine_logs`, every 5 hours new logs are inserted in the logs table, so for example: the machine with ID 7 have a lot of logs but I only need the last one.

I have this query:

```
SELECT MAX(id), machine_id FROM machine_logs GROUP BY machine_id;
```

But when I want to SELECT more columns, MySQL throws this error:

```
SELECT MAX(id), total, machine_id FROM machine_logs GROUP BY machine_id; 

[42000][1055] Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.machine_logs.total' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How can I achieve this without changing the `sql_mode`? Is there any other way to get only the most recent ID in every case? Remember that the query ***returns a lot of results***, not just 1.

EDIT: There are around 400 machines, every machine has logs but I only need the most recent one. The output will have 400 rows, every most recent log associated to every machine.
Every machine has 100+ logs.

Comment: This question is frequent on Stack Overflow. It's usually tagged [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. There are many answers posted. Here's one of mine with a high score: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select more data with subquery as follows:

```
SELECT id, total, machine_id FROM
Machine_logs where id in (select max(id) from machine_logs GROUP BY machine_id);
```